# VBS Regex Only use files with "Y" in the 4th position of filename

Tags: regex, vbscript

So I am trying to open only files with a "Y" in the 4th position in a file name.

Example being:
XXXY.* = YES
YYYX.* = NO

I have tried the following, but with no results.

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "...Y.*"
objRegEx.Pattern = "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]Y.*"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not really need a regex to check if the 4th char is `Y`, use [`Mid`](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_mid.asp):

```
If Mid(s, 4, 1) = "Y" Then...
```

If you need to use a regex, make sure you match any 3 chars from the start of the string and then try to match `Y`:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "^.{3}Y"
```

Here, `^` (start of string anchor) matches the start of the string, `.{3}` matches any 3 chars other than 
 line break chars, and `Y` will attempt to match `Y`. There is no need adding `.*` since partial matches are allowed.